# How to get a single character without pressing enter?

Tags: ruby, getch

How can I get a single keyboard character from the terminal with Ruby without pressing enter?
I tried `Curses::getch`, but that didn't really work for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get single char from console immediately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072623/get-single-char-from-console-immediately)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/2999

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

begin
  system("stty raw -echo")
  str = STDIN.getc
ensure
  system("stty -raw echo")
end
p str.chr
```

(Tested on my OS X system, may not be portable to all Ruby platforms). See http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz5.html for some additional suggestions, including for Windows.

Comment: That works so far, but unfortunately i get a numeric and not a string. du you know how to convert the numeric to the right ascii-character?

Comment: Yes, just use str.chr to get the character corresponding to the numeric value. I've updated the post to reflect that

Comment: Unfortunately since you're in raw mode, control-C gets sent in as a character, not as a SIGINT. So if you want blocking input like above, but still want to let the user hit control-C to stop the program while it's waiting, make sure to do this:
    `Signal.trap("INT") { exit }` 
(see my answer below for a better formatted version)

Comment: The answer below by Andrew (on Jan 25 '13 at 17:49) is better.

Answer (score 72):

Since ruby 2.0.0, there is a 'io/console' in the stdlib with this feature

```
require 'io/console'
STDIN.getch
```

Comment: Link to the documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-getch

Comment: This worked great, provided you check for control-C afterwards: `exit(1) if char == "\u0003"`.

Comment: I didn't even need the `require` :)

Comment: @philant nope, I have a script and calling it via `$ ruby script.rb` works.

Comment: This is probably the best answer nowadays because if functionality has to be changed then the ruby core team (e. g. nobu) can modify / adapt it. This should be better in the long term IMO.

Answer (score 22):

@Jay gave a great answer, but there are two problems:

1. You can mess up default tty state;
2. You ignore control characters (^C for SIGINT, etc).

A simple fix for that is to save previous tty state and use following parameters:

- `-icanon` - disable canonical input (ERASE and KILL processing);
- `isig` - enable the checking of characters against the special control characters INTR, QUIT, and SUSP.

In the end you would have a function like this:

```
def get_char
  state = `stty -g`
  `stty raw -echo -icanon isig`

  STDIN.getc.chr
ensure
  `stty #{state}`
end
```

Answer (score 16):

Raw mode (`stty raw -echo`) unfortunately causes control-C to get sent in as a character, not as a SIGINT. So if you want blocking input like above, but allow the user to hit control-C to stop the program while it's waiting, make sure to do this:

```
Signal.trap("INT") do # SIGINT = control-C
  exit
end
```

And if you want non-blocking input -- that is, periodically check if the user has pressed a key, but in the meantime, go do other stuff -- then you can do this:

```
require 'io/wait'

def char_if_pressed
  begin
    system("stty raw -echo") # turn raw input on
    c = nil
    if $stdin.ready?
      c = $stdin.getc
    end
    c.chr if c
  ensure
    system "stty -raw echo" # turn raw input off
  end
end

while true
  c = char_if_pressed
  puts "[#{c}]" if c
  sleep 1
  puts "tick"
end
```

Note that you don't need a special SIGINT handler for the non-blocking version since the tty is only in raw mode for a brief moment.

Comment: This answer is great, and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much for exceptionally functional code!

Comment: `Signal.trap('INT') { exit }` makes the program exit when control-C is pressed (unless it's bypassed by other means) and definitely works in 1.9.2-p290, so I don't know what "did not work for me" could mean

Comment: This works in your example, but it definitely does not work if you're using `STDIN.getch`. Then your SIGINT gets interpreted as `"\u0003"`. Or maybe something else depending on your terminal.

Answer (score 13):

#### Note: This is and old answer and the solution no longer works on most systems.

But the answer could still be useful for some environments, where the other methods don't work. Please read the comments below.

---

First you have to install highline:

```
gem install highline
```

Then try if the highline method works for you:

```
require "highline/system_extensions"
include HighLine::SystemExtensions

print "Press any key:"
k = get_character
puts k.chr
```

Comment: Warning: a recent commit removed this feature from highline. See https://github.com/JEG2/highline/issues/50

Comment: this does NOT work: it requires that you hit the <enter> key. Incidently, it also takes in the \n character.

Comment: This [example](https://github.com/JEG2/highline/blob/master/examples/get_character.rb) works for me on Ruby 2.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: Works on Ruby 1.9.3 and Windows XP without need to press enter (tested on pry). ps Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

And if you are building **curses** application, you need to call

```
nocbreak
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html#method-c-cbreak