# How do i output to console while providing input as well?

Tags: python, multithreading, console, irc

Essentially, i want what is in this thread: [Output to console while preserving user input in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374319/output-to-console-while-preserving-user-input-in-ruby), but in Python. I have googled for quite a while, and found an ALMOST working solution, except that it blocked the main thread, as long as i wasn't typing anything in and pressing enter.

Some output of what i don't want to happen is here:

```
/raw:jtv!jtv@jtv.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #cobaltstreak :USERCOLOR ullr_son_of_sif #DAA520
```

Some example input of what i want is:

```
:jtv!jtv@jtv.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #cobaltstreak :USERCOLOR ullr_son_of_sif #DAA520
/raw
PRIV:jtv!jtv@jtv.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #cobaltstreak :SPECIALUSER nightbot subscriber
MSG #cobaltstreak :This shouldn't be here, but on the same line with /raw
```

This meaning, i want the bottom line of the console to preserve input, while outputting everything happening in the main thread without affecting input.

My current code is:

```
def console(q, m, lock):
    while 1:
    raw_input()   # After pressing Enter you'll be in "input mode"
    with lock:
        i = raw_input('> ')
        cmd = i.split(' ')[0]
        msg = i.strip(cmd + ' ')
    q.put(cmd)
    m.put(msg)
    if cmd == 'quit':
        break
```

as well has:

```
cmd = cmd_queue.get()
msg = msg_queue.get()
action = cmd_actions.get(cmd)
if action is not None:
    action(stdout_lock, msg)
```

Note the code above is the very first couple of lines in my while loop.

I am on Windows and using python 2.7.6

Comment: Do you have to output to console? This seems trivial in a GUI

Comment: I know i could, but if you can point me to a NICE looking gui, and not an XP or 2000 gui, then be my guest, and i will do it :P

Comment: Ok, looks like gui2py will do. Gonna keep searching though, just in-case i find one i like better.

Comment: however, if someone could tell me how to do it in console, it would be much appreciated ;)