# ruby read character in cygwin terminal

Tags: ruby, cygwin, char

I'm trying to read one character at a time in a ruby running in cygwin.

`STDIN.getc` returns the characters but only after I pressed enter:

```
STDOUT.sync = true
while true
    STDIN.getc
    puts "HELLO"
    STDOUT.flush
end
```

test session:

```
aa
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
```

How can I read a character?

Comment: Since Cygwin, look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174933/how-to-get-a-single-character-in-ruby-without-pressing-enter/174967#174967

Comment: @dexter: working alone in a simple test app, but when I put it in my app ruby crashes :/

Answer (score 0):

use io-console, at later Ruby1.9.3

```
require 'io/console'

# input 3 chars and escape

buf = ''
3.times do
  buf << STDIN.getch
end

print "Your input is '#{buf}'"
```