# Get single char from console immediately

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to get each char from STDIN once it is provided (without waiting for return key)?

Comment: stdin is not necessarily (or even usually) a tty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are numerous ways to do this, and besides gems you can directly manipulate with terminfo through gems for termios, ncurses or stty program.

```
tty_param = `stty -g`
system 'stty raw'

a = IO.read '/dev/stdin', 1

system "stty #{tty_param}"

print a
```

Comment: This should be deprecated in favor of @J-_-L 's answer.

Answer (score 68):

This is possible with Ruby 1.9.3's new `getch` method:

```
require 'io/console'
input = STDIN.getch
```

Docs (Core): http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#class-IO-label-io-2Fconsole

Docs (Lib):  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-getch

Source: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/ext/io/console

Comment: A pointer to the docs would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, shout out to you in this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20081966/8047

Comment: Don't forget to add `exit if input=="\u0018" or input=="\u0003"` if you are in a loop

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Highline](http://rubygems.org/gems/highline) gem:

```
require "highline/system_extensions"  # gem install highline
include HighLine::SystemExtensions

print "Enter one character:  "
char = get_character
puts char.chr
```

*from [JEG II's blog](http://graysoftinc.com/my-projects/i-just-want-one-character).*