# Ruby STDIN.getc does not read char on reception

Tags: ruby, stdin, getc

Seems that Ruby IO#getc wait until receiving a \n before returning the chars.

If you try running this script:

```
STDOUT.sync = true
STDIN.sync = true
while data = STDIN.getc
  STDOUT.puts "Char arrived"
end
```

It will return one "Char arrived" per char sent to stdin, but only after a \n has been sent.

Seems that all char are buffered even if I write STDIN.sync = true.

Does anyone knows how to make the script print "Char arrived" right after a char has been sent to STDIN ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Single Char from Console Immediately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072623/get-single-char-from-console-immediately) or [How to Get a Single Character in Ruby without Pressing Enter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174933/how-to-get-a-single-character-in-ruby-without-pressing-enter) (which have several good answers on how to solve this).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was [an answer from Matz](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/2999) :)

**UPDATE**

Also, you can use gem entitled [highline](http://highline.rubyforge.org/doc/), because using above example may be linked with strange screen effects:

```
require "highline/system_extensions"
include HighLine::SystemExtensions

while k = get_character
  print k.chr
end
```

Comment: +1 for citing a post from over 11.5 years ago. :) See the question I linked to for more answers that you can compile into yours.

Comment: Yeah, that post is ancient, but as you can see it's still actual :D

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. This makes my day. It explains some strange behaviour I had with other programs.

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from from [another answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174933/how-to-get-a-single-character-in-ruby-without-pressing-enter).

```
def get_char
  begin
    system("stty raw -echo")
    str = STDIN.getc
  ensure
    system("stty -raw echo")
  end
  str.chr
end

p get_char # => "q"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27021816/203673 and its comments are the best answer in the ruby 2+ world. This will block to read a single character and exit when ctrl + c is pressed:

```
require 'io/console'

STDIN.getch.tap { |char| exit(1) if char == "\u0003" }
```

Answer (score 0):

From  https://flylib.com/books/en/2.44.1/getting_input_one_character_at_a_time.html

```rb
def getch
  state = `stty -g`
  begin
    `stty raw -echo cbreak`
    $stdin.getc
  ensure
    `stty #{state}`
  end
end

while (k = getch)
  print k.chr.inspect
  sleep 0.2
end
```