# Handle single character user input without pressing enter

Tags: ruby, input, keypress

I am writing a tiny interactive command line tool prompting the user to press a numeric key. It should continue directly after the first key press/input.

Currently I am doing this to capture the user's input

```
puts "yes, please ..."
gets.chomp
```

... however this requires pressing "enter" to confirm the input. How can return the input value right after the first key press?

Comment: Looks like it has been asked before

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072623/get-single-char-from-console-immediately][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072623/get-single-char-from-console-immediately

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
puts 'Do you want to proceed? y/n'

loop do
  system("stty raw -echo")
  c = STDIN.getc
  system("stty -raw echo")

  case c
  when 'y'
    puts 'Yes'
    break
  when 'n'
    puts 'No'
    break
  else
    puts 'Please type "y" or "n"'
  end
end
```