# Get user input while still typing (in a terminal app)

Tags: ruby, terminal

I want to read user input from STDIN and process the preliminary input while the user is still typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A previous answer has some ruby code which enables this behaviour.

[How to get a single character without pressing enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174933/how-to-get-a-single-character-without-pressing-enter/8274275#8274275)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading something like http://ruby.runpaint.org/io

Answer (score 0):

Call `STDIN.getc` to get individual characters that the user types.

Comment: The problem with `STDIN.getc` is that it blocks until the first newline.