# Adding modifier-based keyboard shortcuts to a Ruby command-line application

Tags: ruby, command-line, signals

- I have a Ruby command line application
- The navigation is mostly handled by the user entering a menu selection at a prompt
- There are times when the prompt is being used to capture input that is not a navigation directive
- I would like to offer an alternative way to navigate in these situations
- Currently, I trap SIGINT and SIGQUIT (`Ctrl-c` and `Ctrl-\`) to offer some non-prompt-based navigation
- But the number of signals you can trap is very limited ([apparently 3?](https://superuser.com/questions/343031/sigterm-with-a-keyboard-shortcut))

**What is the best way to add modifier-based keyboard shortcuts to a command-line Ruby application?**

Answer (score 0):

Install highline gem - should permit you to trap all kinds of key combinations (without requiring the user to press enter after the key). See this question for some more detail: [How to get a single character without pressing enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174933/how-to-get-a-single-character-without-pressing-enter)

If you do use highline, at least in my testing, you may (or may not) be able to use Kernel.trap to grab key events like Ctrl-C so you should handle those manually. Highline will trap any key and let you detect ctrl-d vs d. It won't detect the difference between ctrl-d and ctrl-shift-d however, nor does it distinguish alt-d from d. Here's some basic code:

```
require "highline/system_extensions"
include HighLine::SystemExtensions

print "Press any key:"
k = get_character
Kernel.abort("\nCtrl-C - exiting..\n") if k == 3
puts
puts k.chr
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Steve.  I've tried it out and I'm not sure how it helps me add keyboard shortcuts though.  You do in fact have to hit enter to continue execution from `get_character` (this is actually mentioned in the other SO question you link to).  Also, this would capture the first non-modifed character I put in at the prompt (which remember is already is use for other purposes), which I do not want.  I want to capture ONLY modified (Ctrl/Alt/etc) keystrokes.

Comment: Late response but I think you have to capture everything and pass along the keys you don't want to handle to whatever part of the system will handle them (or dump them if they are insignificant/ignored).