# Ruby - Character-wise IO.select

Tags: ruby, io

Is there a way to have `IO.select` return a single input character without receiving an `EOF`? I would like to be able to read user input from the keyboard the same way I read from any other stream, like an open TCP socket connection. It would allow me to make an event loop like this:

```
loop {
  rd, _, _ = IO.select([long_lived_tcp_connection, stdin])

  case rd[0]
  when long_lived_tcp_connection
    handle_server_sent_event(rd[0].read)
  when stdin
    handle_keypress(rd[0].read)
  end
}
```

I've been looking into `io/console` but it doesn't quite give me this capability (although `IO#getch` comes pretty close).

Comment: *"although `IO#getch` comes pretty close`"* - what's missing?

Comment: I can't use `IO#getch` in the `IO.select` block above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set stdin to raw mode (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14527475/477037)):

```
begin
  state = `stty -g`
  `stty raw -echo -icanon isig`
  loop do
    rd, _, _ = IO.select([$stdin])
    handle_keypress(rd[0].getc)
  end
ensure
  `stty #{state}`
end
```

[`IO#getc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/IO.html#method-i-getc) returns a single character from stdin. Another option is [`IO#read_nonblock`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/IO.html#method-i-read_nonblock) to read all available data.

Comment: Awesome! This mostly works, except the `IO#getc` seems to block even if there is data to be read. Using `IO#getch` works as expected though :)

Comment: Interesting, `getc` doesn't block on my system (Ruby 2.1, OS X)

Answer (score 0):

To read one character at a time I would use:

```
STDIN.each_char {|char| p char}
```